# typescript function to compress a string

Tags: string, typescript, functional-programming

I have an assignment in which I need to create a function that takes a string as input and returns a “compressed” version of it, where identical consecutive characters appear as the character followed by its count. For example:
runLengthEncoding("aaaabbbccd"); // ==> 'a4b3c2d'

I need to do it in a functional programming paradigm which means every variable needs to be const and no loops are allowed.

I have the ramda library which I can use , any ideas?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

As this is a homework question I'll only give two pointers here.
I hope this will be enough.

1. You can use the [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function on a string to convert it to an array of characters.
2. You can use the [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function to alter an array in a functional manner and write it back to a single variable

Answer (score 0):

Compress string using gzip and native browser APIs:

```js
export const compress = async (
  str: string,
  encoding = 'gzip' as CompressionFormat
): Promise<ArrayBuffer> => {
  const byteArray = new TextEncoder().encode(str)
  const cs = new CompressionStream(encoding)
  const writer = cs.writable.getWriter()
  writer.write(byteArray)
  writer.close()
  return new Response(cs.readable).arrayBuffer()
}

export const decompress = async (
  byteArray: string[],
  encoding = 'gzip' as CompressionFormat
): Promise<string> => {
  const cs = new DecompressionStream(encoding)
  const writer = cs.writable.getWriter()
  writer.write(byteArray)
  writer.close()
  const arrayBuffer = await new Response(cs.readable).arrayBuffer()
  return new TextDecoder().decode(arrayBuffer)
}
```